# Why is stockfish not accepting my move?

Tags: engines, stockfish, computer-chess, uci

I am trying to play with stockfish from terminal.

I entered the following commands:

```
position startpos e2e4
d
```

The output was:

[image: stockfish output]

Why is stockfish not accepting my move?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an issue with the syntax you are using. According to the [UCI protocol](http://wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/UCIProtocol.html) you should use `position startpos moves e2e4`, i.e., the **moves** keyword is missing in your command.

Comment: Thank you! Checked the syntax many times, but I was somehow blind to the mistake.

Comment: Sir, I am now able to make the 1st move. How to make the 2nd move?

Comment: Both `position moves c7c6` and `moves c7c6` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: UCI is stateless, so you need to send the list of moves from the beginning anew, e.g., `position startpos moves e2e4 c7c6` (the protocol is not really designed for manual usage)

Comment: Thank you, very grateful! 